# OpenGL debugging what is the ID parameter for the error callback function?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml) for the error callback function states:

> Each time a debug message is generated the debug callback function will be invoked with `source`, `type`, `id`, and `severity` associated with the message, and `length` set to the length of debug message whose character string is in the array pointed to by `message`. `userParam` will be set to the value passed in the `userParam` parameter to the most recent call to `glDebugMessageCallback`.

Source refers to the type of the source as explained in the enumerator documentation.

Type refers to the type of the event that triggered the callback.

Severity refers to the severity of the error.

Length is the size in bytes of the message string.

Message is the pointer to the message string.

UserParam is some pointer defined by the user, could be a function, a structure, null, a memory mapped peripheral...

What on earth is ID? The offending object? (Shader, Program, Texture)

The window ID? The id of the current OpenGL context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All OpenGL errors in debug output have an ID. This, along within the message type and severity, is used to identify a *specific* error. For errors generated by the system, the IDs are implementation-defined. However, if the error comes from a [standard OpenGL error](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors), then it usually is the enumerator error category (`GL_INVALID_ENUM`, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, etc). User-created messages can be given their own IDs.

The point of the ID is to be able to identify the specific error message, thus allowing you to use interfaces like `glDebugMessageControl` to cull out that specific error.

Answer (score 2):

It's the identifier of the message, as detailed in the related function [`glDebugMessageInsert`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageInsert.xhtml):

> `id` is available for application defined use and may be any value. This value will be recorded and used to identify the message.